# How do I provide ObjectContent that is a string

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a unit test which tests the scenario where a body is sent in the request which is a plain string, i.e. not parseable as JSON.

In this test, I'm setting the `HttpRequestMessage` something like this:

```
var ojectContent = new ObjectContent(typeof(string)
                        , "aaaaa"
                        , new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
httpRequestMessage.Content = objectContent;
```

The problem is, when I debug the code, the request body has been set to `"aaaaa"` (note the additional quotes) which is enough to cause the deserialisation code to treat the request body differently, meaning I can't test what I mean to test. I need the request body to be `aaaaa`.

Can anyone advise how I can set up the test so that the request body does not contain these quotes?

Edit: I have also tried `new ObjectContent(typeof(object)...` and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to bypass the `MediaTypeFormatter` by using `StringContent` instead of `ObjectContent`:

```
 var content = new StringContent("aaaaa");
 httpRequestMessage.Content = content;
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so I needed to create a media type formatter that didn't interfere with the input in any way. I used this:

```
private class DoNothingTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
        {
            public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
            {
                return false;
            }

            public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
            {
                if (type == typeof(string))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
            {
                var myString = value as string;
                if (myString == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Everything is supposed to be a string here.");
                }

                var length = myString.Length;
                var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);

                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, length));
            }
        }
```

Then, when I want to generate the body of the `HttpRequestMessage', I do so like this:

```
objectContent = new ObjectContent(typeof(string)
                        , "not json"
                        , new DoNothingTypeFormatter());
```